# Adding glyphicon alters size of textbox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, glyphicons, search-box

I'm building a web page using Bootstrap that has a list box populated with names and a search box for filtering those names. The search box has a `glyphicon-remove` button that appears when typed in. When clicked, the button clears the search box. My problem is that the icon causes the size of the search box to shrink, and I can't figure out why that's happening.

**Here's what it looks like:**

[image: Search Box With Icon]

**Here's what it should look like:**

[image: Search Box without icon]

I can fix the problem by giving it a set width using CSS, but I want it to resize with the window like the rest of the form.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<form>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="txtFilter">Select A User</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtFilter" placeholder="Filter by name">
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove filter-icon"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="lstUsers" size="8"></select>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.filter-icon{
cursor: pointer;
pointer-events: all;
z-index: 3;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the icon disappears the box doesn't seem to change shape. Are you sure there isn't any other css you have that might be conflicting? Otherwise there doesn't seem to be another explanation since the code you provided doesn't produce the error.

```css
.filter-icon{
cursor: pointer;
pointer-events: all;
z-index: 3;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<form>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="txtFilter">Select A User</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtFilter" placeholder="Filter by name">
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove filter-icon"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="lstUsers" size="8"></select>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem isn't that the box changes shape when typing. It's that it's permanently smaller only if the icon is there. It displays the correct size if I delete the line: <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove filter-icon"></span>. I suspect there's some conflicting CSS, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Code

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SSSSSS</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<form>
 <div class="col-lg-12 form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="txtFilter">Select A User</label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">      
  <input id="txtFilter" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter by name">
  <span id="searchclear" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</div>


    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="lstUsers" size="8"></select>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#searchclear {
    position: absolute;
    right: 18px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 14px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Jquery

```
$("#searchclear").click(function(){
    $("#txtFilter").val('');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#searchclear').css("display","none");
$('#txtFilter').keyup(function () { 
 $('#searchclear').css("display","block");
});
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however when I use your code it places the icon outside of the search box.

Comment: you can increase in CSS  #searchclear right property value.

Comment: Ah. Ok. I was able to make it work using a variation of your code. The key was changing the 'input-group' class to 'form-group'. I was then able to align the icon by adding right: 50px; top: 25px to my CSS. I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using a variation of Kasunjuth Bimal's code below. The key was I needed to change the 'input-group' class to 'form-group'. Then I was able to re-align the icon with some additional CSS. Here's my updated code:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="txtFilter">Select A User</label>
    <div class="form-group relative">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtFilter" placeholder="Filter by name">
        <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove filter-icon"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="lstUsers" size="8"></select>
</div>
```

```
.filter-icon{
position: absolute;
right: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
pointer-events: all;
z-index: 3;
}

.relative{
position: relative;
max-width: 280px;
}
```